# How to handle simultaneous showing of a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating an app using socket-io and one of the function is to show a modal for 5 seconds then hide it when received data from server. Below is my js:

```
  socket.on('receiveData', function(data){                     
      showModal(data);
  });

function showModal(data)
{
      $('#myModal').html("<div class='col-xs-4'><div><img src='/img/" + data.Avatar + "' id='queue_img1' class='img-circle' alt='User'></div></div>");                     
      $('#myModal').show();
      modalTime1 = setTimeout(function() {
          $('#myModal').hide();
      }, 5000);
}
```

But i have problem when I receive data again before the first modal close. It will show the second modal straightaway. In other words, if I receive second data from server after my first modal show for 2 seconds only, it will straightaway show the second modal.

What I want to do is, even though i receive the second data before my first modal close, which means I receive the second data inside the 5 seconds, my first modal will continue showing for 5 seconds. After the first modal show for 5 seconds then only it will show the second modal for 5 seconds.

Then even if I receive second and third data during when it show the first modal, it will prospone until the first modal show for 5 seconds only show the second modal, then after second modal show for 5 second, then it show the third modal. Something like queueing up with each modal must show for 5 seconds.

I can't seem to find a way to prospone the showing of second modal until after the first modal show for 5 seconds. Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: make your modaltimer1 to a global variable and clear the times at the begining of showModal() function, then close the modal before opening a new modal.. you can use $(document).find('#myModal1').each(function(){$(this).hide();}); to close all instances of opened modals

Comment: @Adarsh, I think you misunderstood what I want sir.. What I want is to let my first modal to show to 5 seconds even though I have received the call to show the second modal before the first modal show for 5 seconds. I want a way to prospone the showing of the second modal to after the first modal finish showing for 5 seconds...

Comment: so what you wanted was to make a queue, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the debounce function like so:
`_.debounce(showModal, 5000);`

Which requires the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) library.

Comment: But how do I know how long I have to wait for the first modal to finish showing? Like if I get the second data when the first modal had showed for 3 seconds, I know it left 2 seconds to show. But how do my app know that?

Comment: In that case you take a look at  `_.after()`. Your requirement is complicated to understand